# POST data to python script

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, ajax

I have an html page hosted at my local server, apache2, I want to send some data to a python script and manipulate it, I use the when I use the **action** tag of the form, It doesn't navigate to the next page and when I try Jquery the script doesn't get executed. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Html:

```
<body>
  <div id="Header"></div>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <form name="login-form" class="login-form" action="/cgi-bin/test.py" method="post" onsubmit="validate();return false;">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Enter Your Credentials</h1>
        <span>URL,Admin,Tenant,Password</span>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <input id="Uname" name="url" type="text" class="input username" placeholder="Keystone URL" />
        <div class="user-icon"></div>
        <input id="Pname"name="admin" type="password" class="input password" placeholder="Admin" />
        <div class="pass-icon"></div>
        <input id="oPass"name="password" type="password" class="input password" placeholder="Password" />
        <div class="pass-icon"></div>
        <input id="tenant"name="tenant" type="password" class="input password" placeholder="Tenant" />
        <div class="pass-icon"></div>   
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button"/>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

This way the script gets executed perfectly but doesn't navigate to next page.

Javascript Function:

```
function validate() {
    var un = document.getElementById("Uname").value;
    var valid = false;

    var unArray = ["http://192.168.1.102:5000/v2.0"]; 
    for (var i = 0; i < unArray.length; i++) {
        if ((un == unArray[i])) {
            valid = true;
            break; 
        }
    }

    if (valid) {
        alert("Login was successful"); 
        location.href = 'HomePage.html';
        document.login-form.action='/cgi-bin/test.py';

        return false; 
    } else {
        alert("Login was Unsuccessful");
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the Ajax call that I try to make:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/cgi-bin/test.py",
  data: "stuff_for_python="+document.getElementById("Uname").value,
  success: function(response) {    
      alert(response);      
  },
  error: function(data) {
      alert(data.responseText);
  }
});
```

Python Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi, cgitb 
from StringIO import StringIO
import json
from io import BytesIO
import pycurl

cgitb.enable()
# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

# Get data from fields
url = form.getvalue('stuff_for_python')

print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n\n"
print

print url
f = open('/home/stack/writing.txt','wb')
f.write(url)
f.close()
```

Comment: Your `data:` is in the wrong format. It needs to be in json format, which is `'{"key": "value"}'`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in data value passed by post.
try this:

```
$.ajax(
{
   type: "POST",
   url: "/cgi-bin/test.py" ,
   data: {stuff_for_python: document.getElementById("Uname").value},
   success: function(response)
   {
       alert(response);
   },
   error: function(data)
   {
       alert(data.responseText);
   },
});
```

Comment: I can't seem to write the response in the File now or print it anywhere.